# How to fit 5 bordered divs exactly inside a containing bordered div

Tags: css, layout, html

When I try to put 5 inline-block divs of 20% width with 1px borders, inside a containing div, also with a 1px border, they wrap on to the next line.

They do fit if I get rid of all the borders.

I understand that this is because the divs take up 100% of the containing divs area, including its padding and border area, meaning that they don't fit **within** the borders, so it has to wrap.

My question is how to modify this so that I can make them fit exactly. Surely this is a common problem?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
        <style type=text/css>

            div
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #navBar
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-top: 10px;
                width: 50%;
            }
            .navBtn
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
                display: inline-block;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navBar">
            <div class="navBtn" style="width:20%">Text</div><div class="navBtn" style="width:20%">Text</div><div class="navBtn" style="width:20%">Text</div><div class="navBtn" style="width:20%">Text</div><div class="navBtn" style="width:20%">Text</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As a side note, it's crazy that if I put the 5 divs on their own lines, they get rendered with space between them, hence why they're all on one line. In my real code the divs are generated with php, so it's not long.

Comment: not sure why this was tagged with php.

Comment: OP sez "In my real code the divs are generated with php" (although this is a CSS question).

Comment: Yeah I guess the php part was not really relevant to my actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin:0 -1px 0 -1px` gives you an easy place to start.

Would also recommend using `float:left` for this since `display:inline-block` is buggy in some browsers.

To get your container `<div>` to expand vertically to fit content, just have an element with `clear:both` after your floated ones.

All can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/steve/qEJaA/

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to get rid of the 1px border for your .navBtn class, and create a nested element in each navBtn div:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
        <style type=text/css>

            div
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #navBar
            {
                border-top: 1px solid black;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-top: 10px;
                width: 50%;
            }
            .navBtn
            {
                display: inline-block;
                text-align: center;
            }
.nav-text { border:1px solid #ccc; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navBar">
            <div class="navBtn" style="width:20%"><div class="nav-text">Text</div></div><div class="navBtn" style="width:20%"><div class="nav-text">Text</div></div><div class="navBtn" style="width:20%"><div class="nav-text">Text</div></div><div class="navBtn" style="width:20%"><div class="nav-text">Text</div></div><div class="navBtn" style="width:20%"><div class="nav-text">Text</div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does, at least on the browsers that I tested it out with. My preference is usually to add some additional HTML markup if it seems to simplify CSS rules (within reason) over CSS approaches because I'm not a CSS guru

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a common problem.

There are (at least) two common solutions.

---

The first is have a wrapper element for each child element, and move the `width` to that. The border stays on the child element.

Because your `id` is `navBar`, this is obviously for some kind of menu, so I'm going to restructure your code to add the described wrapper elements, and to make it more semantic.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/wFeYn/

```
<ul id="navBar">
    <li style="width:20%"><a href="#">Text</a></li><li style="width:20%"><a href="#">Text</a></li><li style="width:20%"><a href="#">Text</a></li><li style="width:20%"><a href="#">Text</a></li><li style="width:20%"><a href="#">Text</a></li>
</ul>

#navBar {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
#navBar li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
#navBar li a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

---

The second solution is to use CSS3's [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing).

This is very easy, and all modern browsers support it (unfortunately IE7 [does not](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)).

To use this with your original code you would do:

```
.navBtn
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

If you do care about IE7, then you should know that `display: inline-block` won't work without some simple hacks.

For IE7 support, replace `display: inline-block;` with:

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

That goes for either your original code, or my updated code. But only if you care about IE7.

Comment: Cool, that works too! Is there any reason you used ul and li, specifically?

Comment: There are a couple of reasons. Firstly, what you have is a *list* of links. So the best choice element is `ul` (unordered *list*). And secondly, it eloquently solves the problem of adding an extra wrapper element. (assuming that these will eventually be links) Which looks nicer? `<div id="navBar"><div class="navBtn" style="width:20%"><div class="nav-text"><a href="#">Text</a></div></div> .. </div>` or `<ul id="navBar"><li style="width:20%"><a href="#">Text</a></li> .. </ul>`